# SoapUI ws-security with encrypted/signed Usernametoken

Tags: soap, soapui, ws-security

I am trying to test a SOAP Webservice that uses ws-security for authentication and message encryption.

Now SoapUI does seem to provide functionality in this regard, but I am struggling to perform a simple Username Token Authentication with authenticated encryption.

So far, I could generate a Usertoken by adding a `Username` WSS Entry in the Outgoing WS-Security Configurations.
I was also able to encrypt the body with an additional `Encryption` WSS Entry.

But the UsernameToken remains in clear text (It needs to be encrypted).

Signature generation should be done using hmac with the symmetric key that is used for encryption, but although the algorithm can be selected, the creation fails with the following stacktrace:

```
Mon Aug 08 17:00:36 CEST 2016:ERROR:org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Signature creation failed
   org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Signature creation failed
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:561)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:481)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.build(WSSecSignature.java:386)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wss.entries.SignatureEntry.process(SignatureEntry.java:238)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.wss.OutgoingWss.processOutgoing(OutgoingWss.java:175)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.actions.request.ApplyOutgoingWSSToRequestAction.actionPerformed(ApplyOutgoingWSSToRequestAction.java:55)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
   Caused by: javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: key must be SecretKey
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignature.sign(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:556)
    ... 43 more
   Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: key must be SecretKey
    at org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMHMACSignatureMethod.sign(Unknown Source)
    ... 45 more
```

My WS-Security policy:

```
<wsp:Policy xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702" wsu:Id="UT_policy">
  <wsp:ExactlyOne>
    <wsp:All>
      <wsam:Addressing wsp:Optional="false">
        <wsp:Policy>
          <wsam:AnonymousResponses/>
        </wsp:Policy>
      </wsam:Addressing>
      <sp:SymmetricBinding>
        <wsp:Policy>
          <sp:ProtectionToken>
            <wsp:Policy>
              <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/Never">
                <wsp:Policy>
                  <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                </wsp:Policy>
              </sp:X509Token>
            </wsp:Policy>
          </sp:ProtectionToken>
          <sp:Layout>
            <wsp:Policy>
              <sp:Strict/>
            </wsp:Policy>
          </sp:Layout>
          <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
          <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
          <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
            <wsp:Policy>
              <sp:Basic256Rsa15/>
            </wsp:Policy>
          </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
        </wsp:Policy>
      </sp:SymmetricBinding>
      <sp:Wss11>
        <wsp:Policy>
          <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
          <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint/>
          <sp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey/>
        </wsp:Policy>
      </sp:Wss11>
      <sp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>
        <wsp:Policy>
          <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
            <wsp:Policy>
              <sp:WssUsernameToken10/>
            </wsp:Policy>
          </sp:UsernameToken>
        </wsp:Policy>
      </sp:SignedEncryptedSupportingTokens>
    </wsp:All>
  </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

SoapUI generated request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <xenc:EncryptedKey Id="EK-9AA143BE89F4DC04011470669480690103" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"/>
            <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
               <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                  <ds:X509Data>
                     <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                        <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=Docker Test Root</ds:X509IssuerName>
                        <ds:X509SerialNumber>5</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                     </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                  </ds:X509Data>
               </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
            <xenc:CipherData>
               <xenc:CipherValue>PBgpK0et06jC3MnZAM+GPqQfBRUCVN0khR3uvyCou7thbmMl9xEPT/hhMttuyn80srkHKVAHRxPtsi7qJnLjKIHCmeCr5bWZJy7jUj8OfdoCPhgfDU8M0T7F0z8DQYgIsSweQk1SgXwY4FzoGX7gOvQZQ6NRiDMb0GFMk2jFzL3wUT2Vw9JMglOQX4cWDzhX3Frf+YBCPe415d4UzXgdA79VR4STUKCLhK29rDTCeMZYFl+Iq87sYrdChHVMhDUfx/mZF/9XCrrOzB/rAWoVo/nuZQ5c0FLvsbGL/F1hIdBPHaBbZ4TyDeYK48b3FYbuKRchVGLHGkbp9C0UON1sQQ==</xenc:CipherValue>
            </xenc:CipherData>
            <xenc:ReferenceList>
               <xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-9AA143BE89F4DC04011470669480690104"/>
            </xenc:ReferenceList>
         </xenc:EncryptedKey>
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-9AA143BE89F4DC04011470669480684102">
            <wsse:Username>sts-testuser</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">secret</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">k2BiRYIVNdfi9JPsD2xw/g==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2016-08-08T15:18:00.684Z</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <xenc:EncryptedData Id="ED-9AA143BE89F4DC04011470669480690104" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
         <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/>
         <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
               <wsse:Reference URI="#EK-9AA143BE89F4DC04011470669480690103"/>
            </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
         </ds:KeyInfo>
         <xenc:CipherData>
            <xenc:CipherValue>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</xenc:CipherValue>
         </xenc:CipherData>
      </xenc:EncryptedData>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: no, sorry - i ended up testing without SoapUI :/

Comment: the problem still exists with SoapUI 5.5 - in my case I was choosing hmac-sha1 as signature algorithm - and the signing procedure would fail with approximately the same message. rsa-sha1 would work alright. I tried to play with Custom Key Value, but obviously it must be totally another thing.